# What is the difference between these two ways of telneting

Tags: port, telnet

I'm trying to check to see if a port is open on something. If I

`telnet licensemanager.domain.edu 25734`

then I get a black screen waiting for input (blinking cursor)

but if I `telnet` and then `o licensemanager.domain.edu 25734` it just sits on `Connecting To licensemanager.domain.edu...`

and if I try to connect with something like putty it says `Connection closed by remote host`

My question is: what is the difference? can anyone explain what the functional difference is?

Comment: So the only difference between the two commands is the additional character?  Why are you adding that extra character?

Comment: "telnet xxx" and "telnet" with "o xxx" should behave the same. Regarding putty: do you telnet or ssh with putty? Are you doing all tests on the same machine?

Comment: when you open the telnet prompt `o` or `open` specify to open a session with whatever <server> <port> you need.

Comment: @WernerHenze same machine. and that was my understanding as well regarding the two versions of telnet. While I normally use putty for SSH, it has a telnet option that I tried while I was trying to telnet. I didn't think that SSHing would be very effective telneting

Comment: If you are really interested what is going on you might do a network trace (for example with wireshark) and dig deeper.

Comment: The difference between the first two is that if you open Telnet in interactive mode (o licensemamager...) it doesn't clear the screen first, which is why it seems to hang on "Connecting...". As for PuTTY I'd check to make sure it's configured correctly.